# Empty alt text in title link outputed by view with CCK field

Tags: drupal, view, cck

I have this fields in a view:

```
Node: Nid  
Content: text1 Plain text  
Node: Title  
Node: Teaser
```

(text1 is a CCK textfield).

I want to output "Content: text1" as a title in link "Node: Title". For "Node: Title" I checked "Output this field as a link" and in "Alt text:" I have input pattern [field_text1_value]. In admin mode title displays perfectly, but when I log out there is no title attribute in `<a>` tag at all. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like maybe anonymous users don't have access to the text1 field? Check anonymous user permissions to see.